# Best way to get resultset and calculation from activerecord grouped by total, page or date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model with date, hours and description and want to display this data in a table with paging. I want to sum up hours per date, page and total.

Is this possible with one query or do i have query for my result set, then query for total sum and sum up in view for page sum?

```
# controller
@result = Data.page(params[:page])
@total  = Data.sum('hours')
# @total_page = Data.page(params[:page]).sum('hours')  

# view
@total_page = 0
@total_date = 0  
previous = nil
@result.each do |result|
  ....
  if previous.date != result.date
    @total_data = result.hours 
  else
    @total_data += result.hours 
  end
  ....
  @total_page += result.hours
end
```

Comment: I assume you want to do this for performance? In that case you probably want to let the database backend do the job. What db are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is not primarly performance more the best way todo this task. I am using mysql.

Comment: One thing I don't know if you have considered: If you don't have all the rows from a certain date on the current page, the total per date for that date will be too low.

Comment: You definitely want to do this with aggregate functions in the DB, not in the application.